# Ajax/Jquery - Call javascript function upon data being returned from server/ Parallel SQL query execution using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP array of values. I loop through it, make ajax calls to the server  by iterating through a for loop (I totally understand that making ajax cals in a for loop is not a great idea. Any suggestions/pointers to doing this a bette way would be awesome no doubt. I'd like to seek an answer to this question however please.). The data from the server takes different times based on what is to be processed & returned.

The problem I have is the `showCustomerUsageChart` function call doesn't get invoked at all at any stage. I tried debugging this by setting a breakpoint on this function's entry & see that there is no call made to it at all. However, I can see that the JSON data is being returned by the server at different points in time upon the respective data being available. I understand I've implemented this incorrectly, no doubt.

AJAX world is not all too familiar to me. I have looked up quite a few questions in this forum, but, kind of struggling to put the pieces together.

Could I request help to achieve what I'm after please. I'd be highly grateful to any help.

```
<script>
    var ajaxurl = 'myDbHandler.php';
    <?php for ($k = 0; $k < count($propertyCustomer); $k++) { ?>
        data = {
            'param1': paramFromUser1, 
            'param2': paramFromUser2, 
            'param3': paramFromUser3,
            'lookUpParamId': "<?php echo $k ?>"
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data,function (response) {
            var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
            showCustomerUsageChart(
                "<?php echo $propertyCustomer[$k][0] ?>",
                "<?php echo $propertyCustomer[$k][1] ?>",
                "<?php echo $propertyCustomer[$k][2] ?>",
                "<?php echo $propertyCustomer[$k][3] ?>",
                resp,       
            );
        });
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML/JS generated code ?

Comment: You don't appear to have defined `showCustomerUsageChart` anywhere

Comment: This is really odd behaviour. You have a dataset from the server already, yet are calling the server another N times to get more data. Why not just retrieve *all* data before you load the page, or get it all in a *single* AJAX request?

Comment: In the case of <?php echo $propertyCustomer[$k][xxx] ?> returns a string value, you have to put single/double quotes around your PHP code.

Comment: Hello Rory - Thank you. The `'lookUpParamId': "<?php echo $k ?>"` is the id of the array element as I'm sure you seen. This is the index of an array of SQLs to be executed. I'd like to plot a chart which is the functionality of `showCustomerUsageChart` (This does the work it is meant for corectly. I've tested without ajax) as & when each one of the query has it's resultset available. PHP executes the SQL from the array whose index is `lookUpParamId`. Hence, I'm using for loop.

Comment: Executing heaps of SQLs takes about 2 min which means the user has to wait to see charts until all the SQLs are executed. Hence, I thought of moving over to AJAX to see if I can plot a chart as & when it's corresponding SQL's result set is available.Given the SQLs are all different, how could I run them with one ajax call to the server? I'd love to get some guidance if you are happy to help me please.

Comment: Also, if response is already JSON, you don't need to call parseJSON....

Comment: Adrenaline - The code generated by the page is the same as this one. I've modified the names of variables etc for confidentiality purposes. hence, I illustrated the concept through the code above by changing the necessary variables. If this is a blocker to solving this, that's alright. Thank you heaps. I'll dig around a bit more. In case you can help without it, it would a be silver lining in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's one way to go about it instead, I avoided using php in javascript so the code and markup are cleaner.

To simulate the lag coming from your queries I did this:

**myDbHandler.php**:

```
$number = rand(2, 11);
sleep($number);

echo 'success after ' . $number . ' seconds';
```

The original .php file now looks like this (**test.php**):

```
<?php
// Array filled with testdata:
$propertyCustomer = array(
    array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'),
    array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'),
    array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4')
);

// Make a string that html can handle and also encode the array above to a jsonString:
$json = htmlentities(json_encode($propertyCustomer));

?>

<!-- Echo the string as data-attribute -->
<div id="holdingElement" data-array="<?php echo $json ?>"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

I seperated js from markup, because I can't stand ugly code (**test.js**):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get the array from the element:
    var phpArray = $('#holdingElement').data('array');

    // Console.log for testing:
    console.log(phpArray);

    // Loop through the array with the jQuery each function:
    $.each(phpArray, function(k, phpArrayValue){
        // The makeCall function returns a ajaxObject so the object gets put in var promise
        var promise = makeCall(k);

        // Now fill the success function in this ajaxObject (could also use .error() or .done() )
        promise.success(function(response){
            // When success, call the function and use the values out of the array above
            showCustomerUsageChart(
                phpArrayValue[0],
                phpArrayValue[1],
                phpArrayValue[2],
                phpArrayValue[3],
                response
            );
        });
    });
});



function makeCall(paramId) {
    // Just testdata:
    var paramFromUser1 = 'val1';
    var paramFromUser2 = 'val2';
    var paramFromUser3 = 'val3';

    // Use ajax instead of $.post to use the success function, and return this ajaxObject
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'myDbHandler.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'param1': paramFromUser1,
            'param2': paramFromUser2,
            'param3': paramFromUser3,
            'lookUpParamId': paramId
        }
    });
}

// Function to log the results from the ajax call:
function showCustomerUsageChart(val1, val2, val3, val4, response) {
    console.log(val1, val2, val3, val4, response);
}
```

I hope this makes any sence, and that it works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much Rick. This is 100% what I was looking for. I've been looking to implement this solution for a few months now. Kept getting closer to the solution through different ways but wasn't 100% what I wanted to achieve. Your solution has done the trick. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is faulty there:

```
showCustomerUsageChart(
                    <?php echo $propertyCustomer[$k][0] ?>
```

You have to put a "," after the PHP closing tag.

Comment: So, can you provide the HTML/JS generated code, please ?

Comment: Sure, let me get that . Thank you